# Java program to calculate how many red nodes are in a Red-Black Tree

Tags: java, counting, red-black-tree

I'm building a program to determine how many red nodes are in a red black tree. I have already implemented a RED BLACK BST which builds the tree after reading a text input. I'm stuck on how to count the number of red nodes? I know the red nodes can only be left leaning and a red parent node can't have a red child. What would be the appropriate method on attacking this problem?

Comment: Please share the code you have so far (building the tree and counting nodes)!

Comment: I've added what i have

Comment: You would pass the root node to your countRed method, than recursively call it again with left & right node (while calling isRed). You should give it a try!

Comment: @Alex I've updated my code! I'm currently getting a null pointer exception however

Comment: actually now I'm getting this error: non-static variable root cannot be referenced from a static context when i run it in my main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive solution would look like this:

```
public static int countRed(Node node) {
    int nbRed = 0;
    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    nbRed += countRed(node.left);
    nbRed += countRed(node.right);

    if(node.isRed()){
        nbRed++;
    }
    return nbRed;
}
```

#### Tested

I tested your code with a simple loop:

```
RedBlackBST tree = new RedBlackBST();
tree.root = tree.put(null, 0, 0);

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    tree.root = tree.put(tree.root, i, i);
}
int redTotal = tree.countRed(tree.root);
```

This returns a total of 3 reds. If I inspect it in debug, it's accurate. 
If you feel the value isn't valid, then you should inspect your tree in debug and identify what isn't valid in your structure.

Comment: thank you! However I still get the error: non-static variable root cannot be referenced from a static context when i run it in my main method... and when i change my root node to static then it says that non-static method node cannot be referenced from a static context when i run it in my main method?

Comment: Change 'tree.countRed(tree);' to 'tree.countRed(tree.root);'  AND  'if (root.isRed(root))'  to 'if (isRed(root))'

Comment: Your code would benefit from a little refactoring. the method 'isRed' for instance => it should/could be a method in Node so you would call 'node.isRed()' instead of 'isRed(node)'

Comment: thanks for all your help! It compiles and runs now however it doesn't count the nodes correctly so I guess i'll start over.

Comment: the code for the other methods was provided by the textbook so do you think the problem is in my count method then?

Comment: I tested creating a few node and calling countRed. I inspected the tree structure and the value was a match. If you expect another value, my guess is that the structure isn't built correctly. Anyhow, put a breakpoint and take some time to inspect your structure. You can at least confirm that the count is good, then the issue would be in rotateLeft/right (or the surrounding if-elses).